# c# selecting from list with lambda expression

Tags: c#, select, lambda, indexer

I have a list of my entities and I'm using Select to get some properties from my entity. My entity has a `PrimaryContact` property and this has a `LastName`property. So If I use like this it's working fine

```
var b = items.Select(s => s[PropertyName]); //Property name is "PrimaryContact" it's fine.
```

but If I use `"PrimaryContact.LastName"` this is not working

```
var x = items.Select(s => s[PropertyName]); //Property name is "PrimaryContact.LastName" it's not working
```

`PropertyName` might be evrything: "PrimaryContact.LastName", "PrimaryContact.FirstName", "PrimaryContact.Address.City"

Could someone help me on that please.

Comment: question is updated

Comment: isn't any of the solution working ?

Comment: it'll work only for PrimaryContact.LastName

Comment: so what do you expect all the property like FirstName, City etc ?

Comment: In my case PropertyName might come anything

Comment: @AhrorKayumov Accessing a property by name using indexer is not a standard "entity" operation. You'd better post the implementation of the indexer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one items `LastName` then

```
var x = items.Select(s => s["PrimaryContact"]).FirstOrDefault().LastName;
```

And if you want all items `Lastname` as collection then

```
var x = items.Select(s => s["PrimaryContact"].LastName);
```

if you want all the property then first select with all the property then iterate over it

```
ar x = items.Select(s => s["PrimaryContact"]);

foreach(var p in x)
 {
    // P.FirstName
    // p.LastName
    // p.Address.City
 }
```

Comment: why I cant use var x = items.Select(s => s["PrimaryContact.LastName"]);

Comment: because seems `PrimaryContact.LastName` not collection of last name its a single entity but `PrimaryContact` is collection so you can select them using linq, but why do you this my solution is not best way ?

Comment: because PropertyName might be anything in my case not only PrimaryContact. PrimaryContact, PrimaryContact.LastName (FirstName ...). Category, Category.Name...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var x = items.Select(s => s["PrimaryContact"].LastName);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not compile because `Select` will return `IEnumerable<HisEntity>` and not a single one - so you cant]'t `.LastName`

Comment: @GiladGreen agreed

Answer (score 0):

`Select` returns `IEnumerable` so if you want all the `LastName`s in `items` then:

```
var b = items.Select(s => s["PrimaryContact"].LastName);
```

Otherwise if you want only of one of them then after the `Select` use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var b = items.Select(s => s["PrimaryContact"]).FirstOrDefault().LastName;
```